# Pandas Binning for different sets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, binning

I have a dataframe of baseball players and some of their stats. For example

```
id    | position   |  gamesPlayed
---------------------------------
1      First Base    100
2      First Base    3
3      First Base    45
4      First Base    162
5      Second Base   145
6      Second Base   120
7      Second Base   6
8      Second Base   88
```

I can bin the gamesPlayed for all positions by doing something like:

```
labels = ['everyday','platoon','bench','scrub']
df['playingt_time'] = pd.qcut(df['gamesPlayed'], q=4, labels=labels)
```

But I'd prefer to label playing time based on position. I can do this for every position like:

```
pt1B = pd.qcut(df[df['position']=='First Base']['gamesPlayed'], q=4,labels=bin_labels)
pt2B = pd.qcut(df[df['position']=='Second Base']['gamesPlayed'], q=4,labels=bin_labels)
```

But then to update the dataframe with this playing time label is a but cumbersome, as I have to go through these steps:

```
pt1B.rename("playing_time",inplace=True)
pt2B.rename("playing_time",inplace=True)
df['playing_time'] = ''
df.update(pt1B)
df.update(pt2B)
```

I'm sure there is a way to do this more concisely but for the life of me I just haven't been able to figure it out! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the code below should work. I added [::-1] to the end of your list to reverse the order.

```
labels = ['everyday','platoon','bench','scrub'][::-1]

df['category'] = df.groupby('position')['gamesPlayed'].transform(lambda x: pd.qcut(x,q=4, labels=labels))
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Knew it had to be something easy. Also as a note I had put the labels in the wrong order in my example, but that was fixed in the answer with the [::1] on the labels variable.